# Ejabberd (15.11) crash cause of missing local_config

Tags: erlang, xmpp, ejabberd

After making a fresh installation , My ejab(15.11) server still getting crashed.

**ejabberd-15.11/logs/crash.log**

```
Offender: [{pid,{restarting,<0.366.0>}},{name,ejabberd_listener},{mfargs,{ejabberd_listener,start_link,[]}},{restart_type,permanent},{shutdown,infinity},{child_type,supervisor}]

2015-12-26 08:26:54 =ERROR REPORT====
Error in process <0.631.1> on node 'ejabberd@archie' with exit value: {badarg,[{ets,lookup,[local_config,{hosts,global}],[]},{ejabberd_config,get_option,3,[{file,"src/ejabberd_config.erl"},{line,749}]},{ejabberd_system_monitor,process_large_heap,2,[{file,"src/ejabberd_system_monitor.er...

2015-12-26 08:26:54 =ERROR REPORT====
Error in process <0.632.1> on node 'ejabberd@archie' with exit value: {badarg,[{ets,lookup,[local_config,{hosts,global}],[]},{ejabberd_config,get_option,3,[{file,"src/ejabberd_config.erl"},{line,749}]},{ejabberd_system_monitor,process_large_heap,2,[{file,"src/ejabberd_system_monitor.er...

2015-12-26 08:26:54 =ERROR REPORT====
[{application_master,shutdown_error},{ejabberd_app,{prep_stop,[[]]}},{error_info,{badarg,[{ets,lookup,[local_config,{listen,global}],[]},{ejabberd_config,get_option,3,[{file,"src/ejabberd_config.erl"},{line,749}]},{ejabberd_listener,stop_listeners,0,[{file,"src/ejabberd_listener.erl"},{line,380}]},{ejabberd_app,prep_stop,1,[{file,"src/ejabberd_app.erl"},{line,84}]},{application_master,prep_stop,2,[{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,376}]},{application_master,loop_it,4,[{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,368}]}]}}]
```

**ejabberd-15.11/logs/error.log**
Failed TCP accept: emfile
Failed TCP accept: emfile

Comment: Error report tells that when `ets` (Erlang Term Storage) tries to lookup for `hosts` record in `local_config` table, it gets `badarg`. It happens when `local_config` table does not exist in ets. However it is hard to find the root cause of this problem without more information like your environment, configuration and such.

Answer (score 0):

Your installation deployment is broken. You should look at root cause (check the logs). In your situation the local_config table is seen missing by ets module so something went very wrong before. It may be related to your custom local modules.

Check the log for previous errors.